# Join different tables depending on field values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, join

I have the following sql view result which contains the audited changes for every field for every table in the system:

[image]

In this case the above image tell us that both *read* and *write* permissions were revoked for the user *Lucas* for the subscription called *MySubscription*.

I need to display that info in a grid however that is not what I want to display, I mean, I don´t want to display IDs. I need to display "Read" instead of 50, "Write" instead of 51, "Lucas" instead of 1 and "MySubscription" instead of 6.

To do that I would like to improve the sql view to get the values instead of their IDs as I mention above. The result that I am looking for is this one:
[image]

The database contains the tables *Subscriptions*, *ProductPermissions* and *TenantUsers* to get the needed info using joins.

Could you please give me some clues about how could I achieve what I need? Thank you.

Comment: What you mean by display? Do you want to display the result to an SQL view or directly in the table?

Comment: You talk about join in your subject but then discuss replacement of values in the text which is a bit confusing to me.

Comment: ok, let me update the question.

Comment: I would suggest that you add a new column that will specify the source of your value, based on that, it will be simpler and better to get your data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with a series of `LEFT JOIN`s, some casting might be required to get the datatype of the joining column the same as `NewValue` (I've assumed a column called `Name` in all your joining tables, this may need changing):

```
SELECT  a.AuditLogId,
        a.Operation,
        a.[Table],
        a.RowId,
        a.Name,
        [OldValue] = COALESCE(s_Old.Name, pp_old.Name, t_Old.Name),
        [NewValue] = COALESCE(s_New.Name, pp_New.Name, t_New.Name)
FROM    AuditLog a
        LEFT JOIN Subscriptions s_Old
            ON a.OldValue = CAST(s_Old.SubscriptionID AS VARCHAR)
            AND a.Name = 'SubscriptionID'
        LEFT JOIN ProductPermissions pp_Old
            ON a.OldValue = CAST(p_Old.ProductPermissionID AS VARCHAR)
            AND a.Name = 'ProductPermissionId'
        LEFT JOIN TenantUsers t_Old
            ON a.OldValue = CAST(t_Old.TenantUserId AS VARCHAR)
            AND a.Name = 'TenantUsers'
        LEFT JOIN Subscriptions s_New
            ON a.NewValue = CAST(s_New.SubscriptionID AS VARCHAR)
            AND a.Name = 'SubscriptionID'
        LEFT JOIN ProductPermissions pp_New
            ON a.NewValue = CAST(p_New.ProductPermissionID AS VARCHAR)
            AND a.Name = 'ProductPermissionId'
        LEFT JOIN TenantUsers t_New
            ON a.NewValue = CAST(t_New.TenantUserId AS VARCHAR)
            AND a.Name = 'TenantUsers'
```

If required you could then PIVOT this into one row per transaction:

```
SELECT  a.AuditLogId,
        a.Operation,
        a.[Table],
        a.RowId,
        [OldSubscriptionValue] = MAX(s_old.Name),
        [OldProductPermissionValue] = MAX(pp_old.Name),
        [OldTennantUserValue] = MAX(t_old.Name),
        [NewSubscriptionValue] = MAX(s_New.Name),
        [NewProductPermissionValue] = MAX(pp_New.Name),
        [NewTennantUserValue] = MAX(t_New.Name)
FROM    AuditLog a
        LEFT JOIN Subscriptions s_Old
            ON a.OldValue = CAST(s_Old.SubscriptionID AS VARCHAR)
            AND a.Name = 'SubscriptionID'
        LEFT JOIN ProductPermissions pp_Old
            ON a.OldValue = CAST(p_Old.ProductPermissionID AS VARCHAR)
            AND a.Name = 'ProductPermissionId'
        LEFT JOIN TenantUsers t_Old
            ON a.OldValue = CAST(t_Old.TenantUserId AS VARCHAR)
            AND a.Name = 'TenantUsers'
        LEFT JOIN Subscriptions s_New
            ON a.NewValue = CAST(s_New.SubscriptionID AS VARCHAR)
            AND a.Name = 'SubscriptionID'
        LEFT JOIN ProductPermissions pp_New
            ON a.NewValue = CAST(p_New.ProductPermissionID AS VARCHAR)
            AND a.Name = 'ProductPermissionId'
        LEFT JOIN TenantUsers t_New
            ON a.NewValue = CAST(t_New.TenantUserId AS VARCHAR)
            AND a.Name = 'TenantUsers'
GROUP BY a.AuditLogId, a.Operation, a.[Table], a.RowId;
```

It is a pretty dirty solution, I would be inclined to store this data in the format you want to select it in i.e. instead of 50/51, store read/write directly in the `NewValue` column.

Alternatively, if you did want the second format with one row per transaction then I'd be inclined to store it in this way. It could be worth reading about the [Entity-Attribute-Value Antipattern](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Entity+Attribute+Value+Antipattern).

Comment: I will try this solution and let you know soon. Sadly, the auditing component catches and stores the modified values and has no way to know what the 50/51 values mean.

Comment: I've done this (admittedly back in the SQL2000 days) using the basic query outlined above (the non-pivot one)

Comment: It worked. Probably I should create a job to preprocess this and store the result in a table 'preprocessedauditlogs'. Please, let me know what you think.

Comment: It depends on a number of factors really, how many records in the audit log table, how frequently you need to view the logs in the required format, how often the data is changing. If you only need to run the above query once a day and it takes a few seconds to run then it is probably not worth normalising the data, if you need to view it frequently and it is taking a long time then it is probably worth creating a Snapshot table. I would hazard a guess that the performance of the above will not be poor enough to warrant a new table, but without knowing the full story I couldn’t say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You could `PIVOT` the data and `LEFT JOIN` to the lookup tables. Then `UNPIVOT` if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply need to display words instead of numbers, create a lookup table that maps between the number and the word you want to display:

```
create table NewValueText (
    NewValue integer,
    Description char(20)
);

insert into NewValueText values
   (50, 'Read'),
   (51, 'Write');   --etc.

--MyTable is your table that contains the NewValue column.
select Description from MyTable
    inner join NewValueText on MyTable.NewValue = NewValueText.NewValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try joining in your tables where your values are specific.  You'll need to create a look-up table for other values other than Really it's a dirty solution because it means hard coding your `NewValue` fields into the SQL:

```
...
FROM
    audit LEFT JOIN 
    mysubscription ON audit.rowid = mysubscription.tenantuserid
        AND audit.newvalue = 1
    LEFT JOIN 
    lookup_list ON audit.rowid = lookup_list.lookup_id 
        AND audit.newvalue <> 1
...
```

That may work for you.